# How to perform the task

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jbpm

I am very new to JBPM. I've a .net core API side and front end is Angular 6 application to which I need to integrate JBPM.I am not able to find any sample application or tutorial where I can see these details.

Comment: Please explain what's JBPM is or give a link

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use kie-workbench and kie-server for process authoring and execution. Kie-server provides REST API through which you can execute the process definition. Go through documentation [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.4/userguide/ch17.html#remote.rest) for more details about kie-server REST API